# Composable in NavGraphBuilder re-invoke content every time the app state changes

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I have problem when use Navigation component, whenever state app changed(ex: background backto foreground). The composable content will re-invoked after app back to foreground.

```kotlin
NavHost(navController = navController, startDestination = ArticleNavigation.START) {
        composable(ArticleNavigation.START) {
            Log.d("cuongnvxx", "repeated")
            WelcomeScreens {
                navController.navigate(ArticleNavigation.HOME)
            }
        }
        composable(ArticleNavigation.HOME) {
            HomeScreens(articleViewModel)
        }
        composable(ArticleNavigation.DETAIL) {}
    }
```

Log here

```
2023-06-15 20:21:38.266 22845-22845 cuongnvxx  D  repeated
2023-06-15 20:21:41.288 22845-22845 cuongnvxx  D  repeated
2023-06-15 20:21:43.200 22845-22845 cuongnvxx  D  repeated
2023-06-15 20:21:45.971 22845-22845 cuongnvxx  D  repeated
```

I refered to [compose-sample/jetnews](https://github.com/android/compose-samples/tree/main/JetNews) but they don't happen the same thing.

How not to re-invoked content composable in NavGraphBuilder

Comment: your question is not clear enough, you don't want the composable block to be executed every time you navigate to it?

Comment: I don't want the composable block to be executed every time the app from background to foreground. thank

Comment: can you share more of the code? This sounds like an issue in the Activity or Fragment you are launching your top level composable from ie. are you using `androidx.lifecycle.repeatOnLifecycle` callback anywhere?

Comment: Sorry for being late reply, I fix this issue by increase version navigation latest.